# TailwindCSS not working/showing any results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I got a React App project template that I have to develop on that and I want to use tailwindcss with it. I've installed tailwindcss according to the docs and it doesn't work. Console doesn't show any errors. Here's my files

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

`tailwind.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

`index.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`App.js`

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-red-500">Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I don't know what's going on. I tried `npx create-react-app` as a brand new project which uses React version 18.x.x and tailwindcss works just fine.

Comment: just a guess, but maybe your import order is the issue there (app imported after the .css)

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier tried re-ordering the import didn't work as well